# Is it possible to control the speed of the lapply function?

Tags: r, google-maps

I wrote a script to geocode a list of addresses using R and Google Maps, but it exceeds Google's 10 queries per second speed limit.  I would like to slow this down to 5 queries per second.

My function constructs the URL, and then I call the functions using do.call, rbind, and lapply to create my geocoded dataset.

```
geoc <- function(address){
    out <- tryCatch({
      url <- "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json"
      response <- GET(url,query=list(sensor="FALSE",address1=address))
      json <- fromJSON(content(response,type="text"))
      loc <- json$results[[1]]$geometry$location
      return(c(address1=address, long=loc$lng, lat=loc$lat))
      })
    return(out)
    } 

result <- do.call(rbind,lapply(as.character(sample$location),geoc))
```

Is there a way to slow this down to about 5 queries per second?  It works great if I'm only geocoding 5 or 10 at a time, but anything over there throws Google errors.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe adding Sys.sleep(0.2) to your function would work?

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you CactusWoman!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Sys.sleep` to wait a given time, then proceed. You would not be able to use that R session for anything else, but you can have multiple R sessions running at the same time so that would not prevent you from working in another R session.

Comment: @CactusWoman suggested Sys.sleep(0.2), I might do at least Sys.sleep(0.3) just to make sure you dont run into a possible conflict on google's side (i.e. Too close to call from their end).

Comment: Good suggestion.  Thank you for your help!